# Convert texture to GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking how to convert a GL_RGBA framebuffer texture to GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA texture, preferably on the GPU. Framebuffers apparently can´t have the GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA internal format, thus I need a way to convert.

Comment: `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA` is not a compression format. It's basically shorthand for "compress this... somehow." You should never ever use it for anything; it's always better to pick a [specific compressed image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Compressed_formats). BTW, why do you need to compress this image? It's already taking up space on the GPU, since it's a framebuffer image. So why not just leave it uncompressed?

Comment: The framebuffer is reused. I do not want to use a normal compressed image format, because decompression is taking too long.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at the nvidia texture tools:
http://developer.nvidia.com/content/texture-tools-208-64-bit
You might be able to use the GPU based DXT compression, that would take a bit of research.

Comment: @RobotRock: "I do not want to use a normal compressed image format, because decompression is taking too long." That doesn't make any sense; decompression is *free*. It happens during texture fetching. Indeed, compression is often an *optimization*.

Comment: Excuse me, I did not follow the link. I could indeed use something like DXT and then compress it on the CPU using ie libsquish. (What I ment was, I can't use PNG ie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to perform the compression on the GPU without transfer to the CPU - here's two samples you might be able to repurpose for OpenGL (they're DX based)

1. [GPU accelerated texture compression](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=78)
2. [GPU accelerated texture compression 2](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=79)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Specifically, the function `glGetCompressedTexImage()`, http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetCompressedTexImage.xml, reads back the data from the texture.

Comment: Very nice, although it seems to me that glGetCompressedTexImage() makes the texture data take a trip back to the CPU. Or does it? "If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a texture image is requested, img is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store". @FrankH., could you provide some more info?

Comment: Two steps - read from the framebuffer (object) into a compressed texture via `glCopyTexImage2D()` (that's all on-GPU), and then (if you need to) get the compressed thing out of there via `glGetCompressedTexImage()` (that'll move it off-GPU unless the target is e.g. a PBO).

Answer (score 6):

See [this document](http://www.hlkclan.net/unreal1/UnrealED%20Utils/s3tc/ARB_texture_compression.pdf) that describes OpenGL Texture Compression. The sequence of steps is like (this is hacky - Buffer objects for the textures throughout would improve things somewhat)

```
GLUint mytex, myrbo, myfbo;

glGenTextures(1, &mytex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mytex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &myrbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, myrbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, width, height)

glGenFramebuffers(1, &myfbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, myfbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL_RENDERBUFFER, myrbo);

// If you need a Z Buffer:
// create a 2nd renderbuffer for the framebuffer GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT 

// render (i.e. create the data for the texture)

// Now get the data out of the framebuffer by requesting a compressed read
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA,
    0, 0, width, height, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &myrbo);
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &myfbo);

// Validate it's compressed / read back compressed data
GLInt format = 0, compressed_size = 0;
glGetTexLevelParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT, &format);
glGetTexLevelParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED_IMAGE_SIZE, 

char *data = malloc(compressed_size);
glGetCompressedTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, data);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDeleteTexture(1, &mytex);

// data now contains the compressed thing
```

If you'd use a PBO object for the texture, you'd be able to get away without the `malloc()`.

Comment: Works for DXTC as well. THANK YOU!